# How do I setup a background process on a express.js app hosting on Azure websites?

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment

I have an Express app that is currently running on Azure. It works great, but my Express app has a service which connects to a streaming API and populates the database. This service requires it's own process. Normally when I host this locally I just type

```
node listen
```

to start streaming, and then open another window and type

```
node app.js
```

to start the server.

But how do I do this when launching my node app on Azure?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that your streaming service requires its own process? Node is highly modular and it seems like you could probably modify the streaming app to be a module included into the express app. This would solve your Azure problem and cut down on complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend converting your import process to just an in-process background job, which is trivial in a non-clustered node app. You can do the scheduling via [the cron npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) or one of the many similar modules available. Just code your import routine as a function.

So instead of in `listen.js` having your code just execute top-level, put it into a named function and export it:

```
function populateDatabase() {
  //connect to streaming API
  //populate database
}

module.exports = populateDatabase;
```

Then in `app.js` you can wire that up with `setInterval` or the node scheduling/cron module of your choice:

```
//app.js
var populateDatabase = require("./listen");
setInterval(60 * 1000, populateDatabase);
// rest of app setup/start code
```

Comment: When I launch to Azure my app builds automatically, so I am not too sure what you mean when you say to "code your import routine as a function". Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: This method would work if I was using a REST API. However, I am using a streaming API which needs to maintain an open connection. I think the correct choice would be to just extract my listening service to another git repository then launch that as it's own virtual machine. In any case, I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Streaming or buffered, It makes no difference. Node can maintain 1000s of open connections in each process. You may want to use a different service for loose coupling reasons, but there's no clear technical advantage or requirement to do so.

Comment: But if I opened up a new streaming connection on every x interval of time then that would mean I would be opening up multiple streaming connections. If that were the case that would mean I would be filtering the same data multiple times. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You can't blindly open a connection every x interval. You need to track your state and only open a new one when needed. This is utterly unrelated to whether this code is in your main process or a side process. Don't use setInterval, use setTimeout when the existing connection closes.